# Italian Mathematics

Tags: mathematics

After reading [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7037/10738) question, I remembered seeing on our department webpage somewhere that for PhD studies one must show a competency in either German, French, or Russian, but Italian was acceptable depending on specialty.

> What is this "specialty"? Is there something that that Italian's a specifically known for or is this ambiguous and the answer would differ depending on what department you spoke to?

My only guess would be Algebraic Geometry since there is a Wiki Page Named: [Italian School of Algebraic Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_school_of_algebraic_geometry).

But what separates them from the French, for instance, who are well know for their Algebraic Geometry? Is there something that they did and are still doing well that is notable in some regard?

Comment: One assumes that Italian would be appropriate for any speciality in which there is  sufficient notable original research literature available only in Italian, or for which Italy is currently a centre of expertise.  In addition, Italian would be highly advantageous to someone doing doctoral research into some areas of the history of mathematics.

Comment: Why not ask your department chair for the history behind the rules?

Comment: I have spoke with faculty in our department and I have a reasonably good answer that I will write up when I have a break.